# How to get the dimension of tensors at runtime?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I can get the dimensions of tensors at graph construction time via manually printing shapes of tensors(tf.shape()) but how to get the shape of these tensors at session runtime? 
The reason that I want shape of tensors at runtime is because at graph construction time shape of some tensors is coming as (?,8) and I cannot deduce the first dimension then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the tensors an output of the graph. For example, if `showme_tensor` is the tensor you want to print, just run the graph like that :

`_showme_tensor = sess.run(showme_tensor)`

and then you can just print the output as you print a list. If you have different tensors to print, you can just add them like that :

`_showme_tensor_1, _showme_tensor_2 = sess.run([showme_tensor_1, showme_tensor_2])`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why some tensors are in shape of (?, ?) in tensorflow is that they are  placeholders. It can change during operation depends on your input data.

So you must feed data into the placeholder,so it can tell what is the exact shape of your tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, None))
print(x.shape)  # ( ?,?)
with tf.Session() as sess:

  rand_array = np.random.rand(3, 3)
  after_sess_x = sess.run(x,feed_dict={x: rand_array})
  print(after_sess_x.shape) # ( 3,3)
```